# como puedo restringir palabras ofensivas en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, local-storage

tengo una duda: quiero restringir palabras ofensivas capturadas por localStorage en javascript, como puedo hacerlo? actualmente mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
 /*Funcion de Capturar, Almacenar datos y Limpiar campos*/
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#boton-guardar').click(function(){        
        /*Captura de datos escrito en los inputs*/        
        var nom = document.getElementById("nombretxt").value;
        var res = nom.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nom.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        /*Guardando los datos en el LocalStorage*/
        localStorage.setItem("Nombre", res);
        /*Limpiando los campos o inputs*/
        document.getElementById("nombretxt").value = "";
    });   
});
/*Funcion Cargar y Mostrar datos*/
$(document).ready(function(){                          
        /*Obtener datos almacenados*/
        var nombre = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
        /*Mostrar datos almacenados*/      
        document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = nombre;
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>            
        <title>Ejemplo LocalStorage</title>
        <meta charset=”utf-8″>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Input Nombre</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombretxt"> <br>  <br>   
    <button id="boton-guardar">Guardar</button><br>
    <div>
        <label type="text" id="nombre"></label>
    </div>
    <script src="guardarNom.js"></script>
    <script src="mostrarNom.js"></script>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Como recomendación te diría que uses un diccionario para comparar las palabras "enteras" y no busques subcadenas dentro de las mismas palabras, porque terminarías censurando entradas correctas como "artículo" o "envergadura". He visto varios sistemas con esos problemas.

Comment: hola aeportugal, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tienes algun ejemplo o un link en donde pueda verlo? te agradezco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La idea es crear un **array** donde están todas las palabras que tu consideres como malas **(malasPalabras)**, luego crear un función que chequea si la palabra o nombre en tu caso es una mala palabra **checkMalasPalabras()**, y el evento **click** del botón guardar que invoca a la función **checkMalasPalabras()**.

Agarre solo la parte de tu código para que te guies donde puedes insertar o incluir lo que hice y de alli puedes agregar las demas cosas:

```js
var malasPalabras = ['nalgas', 'basura', 'trasero'];

const checkMalasPalabras = (palabra) => {
  var rgx = new RegExp(malasPalabras.join("|")+"|" + "/gi");
  return (rgx.test(palabra));
}

$('#boton-guardar').click(() => {        
      
  var nombre = $("#nombretxt").val().toLowerCase();
  
  if(checkMalasPalabras(nombre) == true){
    window.alert("Mala palabra encontrada: " + nombre);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Input Nombre</h1> (Malas Palabras para probar nalgas, trasero y basura)
<br> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombretxt"> <br>  <br>   
<button id="boton-guardar">Guardar</button><br>
<div>
  <label type="text" id="nombre"></label>
</div>
```

Espero sea lo que andas buscando. Saludos

Comment: cambiaria esto  `if (rgx.test(palabra)){
    return true;   
  }   
  return false;` por `return (rgx.test(palabra))`

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias @JackNavaRow

Comment: David muchisimas gracias me funciona bien aunque no entiendo porque con la palabra trasero no funciona! me podrias ayudar?

Comment: Dejame revisarlo, te aviso

Comment: @AndersonRodríguez listo puedes revisar nuevamente

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav genial pero me puedes decir que hiciste pues estoy añadiendo muchas palabras a mi codigo y me pasa con algunas que añado. porfavor

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav creo que ya vi lo que hiciste, me surge una ultima duda, como hago para que rexonosca las palabras en masculino y femenino, ejemplo: lindo - linda

Comment: solo modifique el regex y coloque un `|` al final, quedo asi `var rgx = new RegExp(malasPalabras.join("|")+"|" + "/gi");` ahora si puedes colocar todas las que te de la gana, si te gusto mi respuesta no olvides colocarla como correcta por favor, gracias

Comment: Me imagino que creando un listado de palabras femeninas y masculinas como hiciste con las malas palabras. En verdad primera vez que me plantean eso esta buena la pregunta, deberías de formularla como una nueva pregunta a ver que sale de allí. Esta buena la pregunta

Comment: hola david mira me esta sucediendo algo extraño, me sale este error ahora: guardarNom.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'checkMalasPalabras' has already been declared
    at guardarNom.js:1
(anonymous) @ guardarNom.js:1

Comment: cuando te dice `has already been declared` es que la estas creando dos veces, revisa que no la tengas duplicada por alli u otra función con el mismo nombre